# Generate XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table like this -

```
 Version     itemid      sampleid
 --------------------------------
 1             3            23
 1             3            24
 1             4            45
 2             5            24
 2             5            23
```

Where for each version there can be multiple `itemid`, and for each `itemid` there can be multiple `sampleid`.

I want to generate XML for this table in the following manner

```
<UserVersioningHistory>
  <History>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <itemid>3</itemid>
    <sampleid>23,24</sampleid>
  </History>
  <History>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <itemid>4</itemid>
    <sampleid>45</sampleid>
  </History>
  <History>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <BusinessId>5</BusinessId>
    <sampleid>24,23</sampleid>
  </History>
</UserVersioningHistory>
```

Each node here can have only one version and itemid but can have multiple sampleid for corresponding itemid and Version Pair.

As I am not familiar in with generating XML in SQL Server, can someone give me a hint to what approach I should use?

Can I accomplish this task using while loop, or I should do this writing a subquery?

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is not the place where people do work for you, it is the place where the people are helping each other. Read manual for "FOR XML" statement and that's pretty easy to write by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try it out:

```
select * from 
(SELECT
     version, itemid,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + sampleid
          FROM test
          WHERE version = a.version AND itemid = a.itemid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS sampleid
FROM test AS a
GROUP BY version, itemid) as History
for xml auto, root ('UserVersioningHistory')
```

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid WHILE loops unless when truly necessary.

Preferably you would have multiple tags for the SampleId section if more than one exists.
But to give you the result that you want the following would work. (I created a temp table to imitate your situation.)

I used FOR XML to do the XML formatting and had to use a second FOR XML to concatenate the SampleId sepparated by a comma.
STUFF is only used to remove the first comma in the string.

```
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SELECT
        X.Version,
        X.ItemId,
        X.SampleId
    INTO
        #Temp
    FROM
        (VALUES
            (1, 3, 23),
            (1, 3, 24),
            (1, 4, 45),
            (2, 5, 24),
            (2, 5, 23)
        ) X ([Version], ItemId, SampleId)

    SELECT
        T.Version,
        T.ItemId,
        STUFF((
                SELECT
                    ',' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), T2.SampleId)
                FROM
                    #Temp T2
                WHERE
                    T2.Version = T.Version AND
                    T2.ItemId = T.ItemId
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ),
            1,
            1,
            ''
        ) AS [SampleId]
    FROM
        #Temp T
    GROUP BY
        T.Version,
        T.ItemId
    FOR XML RAW ('History'), ROOT ('UserVersioningHistory'), ELEMENTS


    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```